# InstanceVariableAssumption: UsersController assumes too much for instance variable '@user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reek

I'm following Michael Hartl tutorial Rails course. On [chapter 7](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up), I run Reek on UsersController and I got this following warning:

> app/controllers/users_controller.rb -- 1 warning:
>   [1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up):InstanceVariableAssumption: UsersController assumes too much for
>   instance variable '@user'
>   [https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/master/docs/Instance-Variable-Assumption.md]

Here is my code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new user_params
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = t "welcome_to_app"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by id: params[:id]

    return if @user
    flash[:danger] = t "not_exist_user"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit :name, :email, :password,
      :password_confirmation
  end
end
```

Kindly explain why I got this error InstanceVariableAssumption and how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use like this:

```
attr_reader :user, :users
```

Then all @user, @users can be written like `user` or `users`.

Answer (score 6):

That looks like one of the smells that reek [recommends disabling](https://github.com/troessner/reek/blob/master/README.md#working-with-rails) on the GitHub page. According to [this bug report](https://github.com/troessner/reek/issues/1133)  filed on the project, it appears this is just due to rails making use/encouraging patterns that reek doesn't like by default.

Answer (score 1):

Instance Variable Assumption says:

> Classes should not assume that instance variables are set or present outside of the current class definition.

Well, this is where **Convention over configuration** comes in Rails. Rails has its own way of doing things, and the class: `UsersController` has a dependency upon the class: `User`.

The variable: `@user` is an instance variable defined in `UsersController`, but this is an object of class `User`. And this is how the things are done in Rails, and you will find it everywhere.

Just assume that this isn't perfect according to [Reek](https://github.com/troessner/reek) gem, but this is how the things are done in Ruby on Rails.